# Upgrading from gradle 5.2 -> 6.0 gives error: could not find or load main class

Tags: gradle, grails, groovy

I'm upgrading gradle for my Grails application from version 5.2 to 6.0 following their official guide: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html

This is not going that well, as I can now not start any of my subprojects. The one I'm testing is called integration, and after the upgrade (and changing compile to implementation), the `build.gradle`  looked like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        maven artifactory
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:$jsonToPojoVersion"
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:$grailsViewsGradleVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:$assetPipelineVersion"
        classpath "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:$groovyVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.plugins.views-json"

apply from: "${rootProject.rootDir}/gradle/common.gradle"
apply from: "${rootProject.rootDir}/gradle/deployable.gradle"
apply from: "${rootProject.rootDir}/gradle/json2pojo.gradle"

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'dk.erst.plandata.integration.Application'
}

dependencies {
    profile "org.grails.profiles:rest-api"

    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: hibernateValidatorVersion
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:cache-ehcache:$ehcacheVersion"

    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: googleJsonSimpleVersion
    implementation group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: "$itextpdfVersion"
    implementation "org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:$xhtmlRenderVersion"
    implementation "com.jcraft:jsch:$jcraftVersion"

    implementation "org.grails.plugins:rendering:$grailsRenderingVersion"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    implementation "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates"
    implementation "net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:$netsfJsonVersion"

    implementation "person-og-organisation:pogo-grails-plugin:$pogoGrailsPlugin"
    implementation "person-og-organisation:pogo-common:$pogoCommonsVersion"
    implementation "beskedfordeler:beskedfordeler-plugin:$beskedfordelerPlugin"

    implementation group: 'dokumentlager', name: 'dokumentlager-grails4-plugin', version: "$dokumentlagerPlugin"

    implementation "erkerne:text-manager-plugin:$textmanagerPlugin"
    implementation "erkerne:text-manager-api:$textmanagerApiVersion"

    implementation "sag:sagslager-grails-plugin:$sagslagerGrailsPlugin"
    implementation "sag:sag-enums:$sagEnumVersion"
    implementation "sag:sagslager-api:$sagslagerApiVersion"
    implementation "sag:sagslager-interface:$sagslagerInterfaceVersion"
    implementation "sag:sagsindeks-grails-plugin:$sagsindeksPluginVersion"
    implementation "sag:sagsindeks-object-marshallers:$sagsindeksPluginVersion"
    implementation "sag:sagsindeks-api:$sagsindeksApiVersion"

    implementation project(":model")
    implementation project(":utils")
    implementation project(":validering")
}

assets {
    minifyJs = false
    minifyCss = false
    maxThreads = 1
}
```

However, I can no longer run my application, and now get this error:

```
> Task :integration:bootRun FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class dk.erst.plandata.integration.Application
```

This was not a problem in gradle 5.2. I have tried to apply the "application" plugin, changing `springBoot {}` to `application {}` but it made no difference. I have also tried to remove `mainClassName` altogether, but same result.

I can see that other grails projects in my unit use gradle 6.0, but don't even specify `mainClassName` and it seems to work.

Comment: It's hard to say with just what you have here, esp w/ the `apply from:` files not provided...  Primary areas of interest would be `sourceSets`, making sure your source code is in the proper place, the basics..  Failing that, debugging strategies, just from what's here, would be going back to the original and seeing if that works.  Changing things very sparingly and see if you find a minimal upgrade arrangement that works, and then see what's fundamentally different..  Also, you could do things like root through the `build/` folder to to see if the file is compile?  I'd start w/ those things..

Comment: How are you running your application?  Looks like "bootRun", but from terminal/command line, in an IDE, something else?  Whenever I have changed gradle versions, I have to do a gradle reload in IntelliJ.  I also don't personally have any springBoot or application block, but I'm using gradle 7 so maybe that's a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I have a few things to try out now!

Answer (score 0):

As was already noted in the comments, it’s hard to say what’s going wrong with this little information and especially without knowing what the applied Gradle scripts contain. So here’s just a guess: I’ve sometimes seen weird errors when upgrading the Gradle version because of outdated `build/` and/or `.gradle/` directories. Deleting those directories after an upgrade often does wonders.